# Delete allocated (new) object outside of its scope

Tags: c++

Currently I am facing a problem with some memory management in C++.

```
void SomeClass::cpy(char** dest, const char* origin)
{
  int len = strlen(origin);
  char* tmp = new char[len+1];
  strncpy(tmp, origin, len);
  tmp[len] = '\0';
  *dest = tmp;
}
```

The function call looks like that

```
for(auto &person : persons)
...
    SomeClass::cpy(&(person.name_), new_name);
...
```

My problem is to delete the tmp variable outside of its scope. I can't delete it at the end of this scope as I need its value. Using the classes destructor with `delete[] name_;` seems to violate the memory.

Comment: What do you mean _outside its scope_?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use `std::string` and reference parameters instead of mucking about with manual memory operations and pointers.

Comment: As I am allocating tmp inside the function, I am not able to delete it from anywhere else.

Comment: The beauty (and horror) of dynamic allocation is the scope is what you say it is.

Comment: @Mer0winger _"I am not able to delete it from anywhere else. "_ No, that's a misconception.

Comment: @Mer0winger Sure you are.  You are allowed to delete it from anywhere that you have access to the pointer.  Just make sure that it is deleted *exactly once*.

Comment: A significant amount of horsepower exists in `std::string` exactly because such allocations are unpleasant to handle on your own.

Comment: Is this an exercise or a construct in a "real" program?

Comment: find these on cppreference.com
`std::make_unique`,
`std::unique_ptr`,
`std::make_shared`,
`std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Objects don't have scope, names do. Objects have lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

In modern C++ it is considered a bad practice to use naked pointers for owning objects. Use std::unique_ptr instead which will ensure that memory is freed when it is deleted. And it is preferable to return value from functions instead of using output arguments. Change signature of your method to

```
std::unique_ptr<char> SomeClass::cpy(const char* origin)
```

This way `std::unique_ptr` will be responsible for deleting the memory when it is not needed anymore.

Note, that for your particular use case `std::string` can be a better alternative because it is specifically designed for handling strings.

Comment: *In modern C++ it is considered a bad practice to use naked pointers* is a little misleading.  It is bad practice to use raw *owning* pointers.  non owning pointers are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

A quick walk-through:

```
void SomeClass::cpy(char** dest, const char* origin)
{
  int len = strlen(origin);
  char* tmp = new char[len+1];
```

A block of memory was just dynamically allocated. This block will exist until manually freed with `delete[]`.

```
  strncpy(tmp, origin, len);
  tmp[len] = '\0';
  *dest = tmp;
```

The block of memory previously allocated has been assigned to `dest`. Whoever provided `dest` may use `delete[]` to free this memory at any time so long as it is only done once per allocation.

```
}
```

Now the caller

```
SomeClass::cpy(&(person.name_), new_name);
```

has specified that `person.name_` and `dest` are one and the same. This means that `delete[] person.name_;` is perfectly acceptable.

## However...

This looks like an excellent place to do none of the above and reduce the memory management woes with `std::string`. `std::string` looks after its memory for you.

```
std::string SomeClass::cpy(const char* origin)
{
  return std::string(origin);
}
```

and

```
person.name_ = SomeClass::cpy(new_name);
```

Once `person.name_` is converted from `char *` to `std::string`. But as soon as that has been done `SomeClass::cpy` is redundant because

```
person.name_ = new_name;
```

Will do all of the work for you.

Comment: You can even one up it and use `std::string SomeClass::cpy(std::string origin) { return origin; }`

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. Also opens up the possibility for a page and a half long screed explaining pass by value vs pass by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning tmp into *dest. So when you're done with it you can `delete person.name_` assuming that `person.name_` is a `char*`.